# JPanel displaying weird error when drawing image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, grid-layout

I'm having a weird error with my board game. The board consists of a 2D array with GameTiles, which is a subclass of JPanel. It all works perfectly fine when I have the size (600,500) but whenever I change it I get a weird error in the upper left corner.

Picture of the error (see the upper left corner)
[image: Board error]

What makes it even weirder is that when I created a new project, just to try it out, it worked perfectly. The code is exactly the same for the painting and I'm not experiencing any error with it. Can it be something else that's causing this problem?

**PROBLEM FIXED**

Anser: I accidentally overrided the getX and getY methods of JPanel. I changed the name on them and now it works perfectly.

Reversi.java

```
package org.reversi;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

import org.reversi.gui.GameFrame;

public class Reversi {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
                 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GameFrame frame = new GameFrame("Reversi");
            frame.setSize(600,500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

GameBoard.java

```
package org.reversi.gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameBoard extends JPanel{
private GameTile[][] gameBoard = new GameTile[8][8];

public GameBoard() {
    initiateLayout();
}

private void initiateLayout() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

    for(int row = 0 ; row < 8 ; row++) {
        for(int col = 0 ; col < 8 ; col++) {
            gameBoard[row][col] = new GameTile(col,row);
            add(gameBoard[row][col]);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(int row = 0 ; row < 8 ; row++) 
        for(int col = 0 ; col < 8 ; col++)              
            gameBoard[row][col].repaint();
}
}
```

GameFrame.java

```
package org.reversi.gui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
private GameBoard gameBoard;

/**
 * Creates a new frame.
 * @param gameTitle the title of the frame
 */
public GameFrame(String gameTitle) {
    setTitle(gameTitle);
    gameBoard = new GameBoard();
    add(gameBoard);
}
}
```

GameTile.java

```
package org.reversi.gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameTile extends JPanel {
private BufferedImage image;
private int x;
private int y;

public GameTile(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    try {
        this.image = ImageIO.read(new File("tile.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}
}
```

Link to image (which should be named tile.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JZmI.png

Comment: It makes no sense to call repaint() in paintComponent. Just call one repaint for all of them (in the container). But this is not an explanation for your problem: I think it must be somewhere else

Comment: Can you provide also code where you create & add your "game borad" panel? Do you invoke setOpaque method on the parent component of the game board?

Comment: Why does it not make any sense going through all of the tiles and calling repaint on them? How should I do it other wise?

Code is added and I do not invoke setOpaque on the frame.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner. This may also include linking to an external image or creating your own small image from within the code

Comment: I fixed the problem but I would love an explanation on why it now works. I've posted what fixed it as well as the SSCCE and link to the image that is needed.

Comment: +1 for sscce...why do you have that `getX` and `getY`? BTW that is overriding the extending `JPanel`s `getX` and `getY` method.... and not for your `x` and `y` within the class. Add `@Override` annotation (above the method declaration) and you will see no compile error...+1 @Xeon answered same time :P

Comment: You've overriden `getX()` method from `JPanel` (or to be more precise: from `JComponent#getX()`): "Returns the current x coordinate of the component's origin." But you shouldn't do this because the layout manager will take care of component placement.

Comment: This was the problem, thank you so much for pointing that out. I'm using the coordinates when making a move on the board. If there's some way to make this an answer it would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your comment:

> This was the problem, thank you so much for pointing that out. I'm
>   using the coordinates when making a move on the board. If there's some
>   way to make this an answer it would be great

In `GameTile.java` you have done:

```
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}
```

With this you are actually overriding `JPanel`s [`getX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getX%28%29) and [`getY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getY%28%29) and returning co-ordinates which will affect the `Layout`. This can be seen by adding [`@Override` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) (NOTE not compiler error is thrown thus we are correctly overriding a method from the extending class):

```
@Override
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

@Override
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
```

As @Xeon said you should not set the co-ordinates the `LayoutManager` will do that.

**Solution: (plus extras)**

- Remove those *getters* or rename them appropriately.
- Dont call `setSize` on `JFrame` rather override `getPreferredSize` of `JPanel which is drawn to via`Graphic`s object and return the correct`Dimension`s (in your case the image dimensions) and than call [`pack()`][4] on`JFrame` before setting it visible but after adding components.
- You will need to relocate call to `setLocationRelativeTo(...)` to after `pack()`.
- Better to use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` so `main(String[] args)` method may carry on its execution even after GUI termination.
- Also dont extend `JFrame` unnecessarily.
- Dont repeatedly load the same image in your `GameTile` class rather load the image once and add parameter for `GameTile` to accept an `BufferedImage` ( I figured this out while testing using the internet URL it took forever because it read a new image for each `GameTile` created)

Here are the classes with necessary changes made:

**Reversi.java:**

```
public class Reversi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GameFrame("Reversi");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**GameBoard.java**:

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {

    private GameTile[][] gameBoard = new GameTile[8][8];

    public GameBoard() {
        initiateLayout();
    }

    private void initiateLayout() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/ejmCtui.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                gameBoard[row][col] = new GameTile(image, col, row);
                add(gameBoard[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                gameBoard[row][col].repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GameTile.java:**

```
public class GameTile extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public GameTile(BufferedImage image, int x, int y) {
        this.image = image;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

**GameFrame.java:**

```
public class GameFrame {

   private GameBoard gameBoard;

    /**
     * Creates a new frame.
     *
     * @param gameTitle the title of the frame
     */
    public GameFrame(String gameTitle) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(gameTitle);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        gameBoard = new GameBoard();
        frame.add(gameBoard);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

which would produce:

[image]